# Proguard with Roboguice

Tags: android, android-proguard

I turned on proguard in by application I have a warning in application `onCreate`

```
RoboGuice.injectMembers(_appContext, this);
```

The exception:

```
nalizableReferenceQueue﹕ Could not load Finalizer in its own class loader. Loading Finalizer in the current class loader instead. As a result, you will not be able to garbage collect this class loader. To support reclaiming this class loader, either resolve the underlying issue, or move Google Collections to your system class path.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Finalizer.class
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.getBaseUrl(SourceFile:269)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.loadFinalizer(SourceFile:253)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.loadFinalizer(SourceFile:175)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.<clinit>(SourceFile:100)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$QueueHolder.<clinit>(SourceFile:787)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$WeakEntry.<init>(SourceFile:946)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$Strength$1.newEntry(SourceFile:312)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.newEntry(SourceFile:498)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.newEntry(SourceFile:419)
            at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(SourceFile:2029)
            at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.hasAnnotations(SourceFile:116)
            at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.isBindingAnnotation(SourceFile:180)
            at com.google.inject.Key.ensureIsBindingAnnotation(SourceFile:366)
            at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(SourceFile:338)
            at com.google.inject.Key.get(SourceFile:272)
            at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingBuilder.annotatedWithInternal(SourceFile:82)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ConstantBindingBuilderImpl.annotatedWith(SourceFile:49)
            at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(SourceFile:117)
            at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(SourceFile:59)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(SourceFile:223)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(SourceFile:101)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(SourceFile:78)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(SourceFile:83)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(SourceFile:139)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.getBaseApplicationInjector(SourceFile:59)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(SourceFile:149)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.injectMembers(SourceFile:156)
            at com.package.MyApplication.x(SourceFile:847)
            at com.package.MyApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:243)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4712)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I include in my proguard file:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-keep class roboguice.** { *; }
```

**What else should I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your proguard file

```
-keep class com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer { *; }
```

Comment: @NickF are you sure this proguard file is used?

Comment: if I add:  -dontobfuscate is enough?

Answer (score 2):

Please add below lines into your file it will resolve your issue.

```
     -keep class com.google.inject.Binder
        -keepclassmembers class * {
            @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
        }

        # There's no way to keep all @Observes methods, so use the On*Event convention to identify event handlers
        -keepclassmembers class * { 
            void *(**On*Event); 
        }
        -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
            public <init>(android.content.Context);
            public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
            public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
            public void set*(...);
        } 
        -keep public class roboguice.**
        -keep class com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer { *; }
```

This is as per the official document [here](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/ProGuard)

Comment: can u drop me complete progaurd file it will be eassy to tackle